# android -Launch custom android application from android browser

Tags: android

I've a link like this in my application :

```
http://mywebsite.com/pr-5
```

I want to do something when user opens this link in browser , my application runs and open the data with the id of 5 .

as you can see, I send the id at the end of my url , I want to get the id and shows the data in my app .

To do so , I've added this code to my manifest :

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" >
        </action>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" >
        </category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" >
        </category>

        <data
            android:host="www.mywebsite.com"
            android:scheme="http" >
        </data>
    </intent-filter>
```

But when I enter my address in browser , nothing happens.

Could you help me to do so ?

Comment: what happens if you click on a link with this url?

Comment: @Rithe it opens  the website , it doesn't open application at ll

Comment: is the host of your link  "mywebsite.com" and of your scheme "www.mywebsite.com"? these two have to be identically